# Call application process to download file by oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have two region master details , master updates (interactive grid)and the details uploaded file (interactive active report).
Once click on master region set value in item (p10_id ) and refresh the details  region. In details region I have a button to download all file in zipfile .by redirect to url to call application process by below code

```
 F?p=100:1:session:updatezipfile::::upload_id:&p10_id.
```

But always the item value send null how i can solve this problem  I tried submit item by plsql

```
  Begin 
   Null;
 End;
```

Item to submit P10_Id but also not working fine always the item send null.

Answer (score 1):

i solved this issue by below steps

1- create ajax call back  Name (URL).
        [image]
2- call ajax callback by below code

```
  apex.server.process ( "URL", {
   pageItems : '#P6_UPDATE_ID'
   }, {
   success: function(Data) 
     { 
       apex.navigation.redirect(Data);
     }
  });
```